# I am using a mac and i wanted use cs50 library to make things easier but i am facing constant problems

Tags: c, macos, cs50

```
cd "/Users/vijaykumarbk/Desktop/" && gcc helo.c -o helo && "/Users/vijaykumarbk/Desktop/"helo
vijaykumarbk@a-laptop Desktop % cd "/Users/vijaykumarbk/Desktop/" && gcc helo.c -o helo && "/Users/vijaykumarbk/Desktop/"helo
ld: Undefined symbols:
  _get_string, referenced from:
      _main in helo-faead5.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
vijaykumarbk@a-laptop Desktop % make helo
cc     helo.c   -o helo
ld: Undefined symbols:
  _get_string, referenced from:
      _main in helo-8ff670.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [helo] Error 1
vijaykumarbk@a-laptop Desktop % make helo.c
make: Nothing to be done for `helo.c'.
vijaykumarbk@a-laptop Desktop %
```

Comment: I can't say I think much of CS50 in general or of your plan to use it to "make things easier".  But *you* certainly need to know that its licensed under an open source license that you will need to adhere to if you use it in your projects.  Also, if you are planning to use it in academic exercises then you should definitely discuss that with your instructor first, as they might be of the opinion that relying on CS50 is not acceptable for their assignments.